# How can I use HttpFactory in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I used curl in Joomla,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-API-KEY:' . $api_key,
        'X-SANDBOX:' . $sandbox,
));
```

but now I use HttpFactory for request to api:

```
$options = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-API-KEY:' . $api_key,
    'X-SANDBOX:' . $sandbox,
 );
 $answer = $this->http->post($url,json_encode($data,true),$options);
```

my result body is :

> Unsupported request content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$options` array has to be an associative array like the following:

```
$options = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY' => $api_key,
    'X-SANDBOX' => $sandbox,
);
```

Short explanation: The 3rd parameter of the `post()` method in the `Http` class is expecting `$headers` information in a specific format:

> *An array of name-value pairs to include in the header of the request.*

[Link to Joomla Documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Http.Http.html#method_post)

You can get Joomla help from many experts at Joomla Stack Exchange: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/